# How add hash parameter to url using redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How add hash parameter to url using redirect_to?

For example:

[http://localhost/products/#{page:2](http://localhost/products/#%7Bpage:2)}

Comment: You can change the correct answer to my answer now its has enough votes now. :)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

use something like

```
redirect_to url_for(:action=>:index)+"#order"
```

Answer (score 30):

Best way to do it will be.

```
 redirect_to :action => :index, :anchor => "order"
```

Comment: `redirect_to :action => :index, :anchor => "order"` should work too. `redirect_to` already calls `url_for`/`path_for` internally.

Comment: Yep! It has been like that since Rails <= 1.0.0.