# Working with router.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey!
I have (for instance) this:

```
  @w1 = rand(9999999)
  @w = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(@w1.to_s)
```

and i get : 6437gdfghfijd8794tyr98vdhf (code).. Okei.. In rails How could I put this code in my url..
something like this: localhost:3000/6437gdfghfijd8794tyr98vdhf ?

```
#router.rb
  map.about '/@w', :controller => 'ans', :action => 'index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How add hash parameter to url using redirect_to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923607/how-add-hash-parameter-to-url-using-redirect-to)

This should give u some idea.

Or if u want to use it in your view: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to